# JavaScript keep the original array in recursive function

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I would like to keep the original array to return the original index in recursive function.
The original code is from rbarilani https://gist.github.com/rbarilani/0d7946510740f9e1e8fa .
Please help to advise how to change the line

```
const numList = [3,9,8,4,5.5,7,10.07];
```

```
function subsetSum(numbers, target, partial) {
  var s, n, remaining;
  const numList = [3,9,8,4,5.5,7,10.07]; **//<<<<<<<The code I want to change, please advise how to make it as function input**     
  partial = partial || [];

  // sum partial
  s = partial.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return Math.round((a + b)*100)/100;
  }, 0);

  // check if the partial sum is equals to target
  if (s === target) {
    console.log(numList);
    partial.forEach(function(findIndex){
    console.log(findIndex, 'is at position ', numList.indexOf(findIndex));
});
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    n = numbers[i];
    remaining = numbers.slice(i + 1);
    subsetSum(remaining, target, partial.concat([n]));
  }
}

subsetSum([3,9,8,4,5.5,7,10.07],15.57);
```

thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a closure around your recursive function like:

```js
function findSubSet(numList,targ){
 function subsetSum(numbers, target, partial) {
  var s, n, remaining;    
  partial = partial || [];

  // sum partial
  s = partial.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return Math.round((a + b)*100)/100;
  }, 0);

  // check if the partial sum is equals to target
  if (s === target) {
    console.log(numList);
    partial.forEach(function(findIndex){
      console.log(findIndex, 'is at position ', numList.indexOf(findIndex));
    });
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    n = numbers[i];
    remaining = numbers.slice(i + 1);
    subsetSum(remaining, target, partial.concat([n]));
  }
 }
 subsetSum(numList,targ);
}

findSubSet([3,9,8,4,5.5,7,10.07],15.57);
```

Your function `subsetSum()` does not return anything, so it is more like a recursive procedure really. Everything in your code stays the same, the only change I made was to create the function `findSubSet()` around it, so it keeps the original `numList` array in its scope to be used by all recursive calls of `subsetSum()`.

Using the closure idea, you can simplify your code even further, as the `target` value is another variable that does not need to be passed down:

```js
function findSubSet(numList,target){
 function subsetSum(numbers,partial) {
  var s, n, remaining;

  // sum partial
  s = partial.reduce((a, b)=>Math.round((a + b)*100)/100, 0);

  // check if the partial sum is equals to target
  if (s === target) {
    console.log("found a subset in "+numList.join(" ")+" for target "+target+":");
    partial.forEach(idx=>console.log(idx, 'is at position ', numList.indexOf(idx)));
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    subsetSum(numbers.slice(i + 1), partial.concat([numbers[i]]));
 }
 subsetSum(numList,[]);
}

findSubSet([3,9,8,4,5.5,7,10.07],17.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend generators as they are perfectly suited for this kind of problem. The benefit of the generator is that it is pauseable and cancellable. This allows you to easily find **one** solution to the problem, or **all** solutions, without having to change the code.

```js
function* subsetSums(numbers, target, precision = 2)
{ function* solve(i, q, r)
  { if (q == 0) return yield r
    if (numbers.length < i || q < 0) return
    // solve with this number
    yield *solve
      ( i + 1
      , round(q - numbers[i], precision)
      , [...r, {pos: i, n: numbers[i]}]
      )
    // solve without this number
    yield *solve(i + 1, q, r)
  }
  yield *solve(0, target, [])
}
```

Notice how I separated `round` into its own function. Isolating concerns is an effective programming technique as it makes your functions easier to read/write and promotes code reuse within other areas of your program

```js
const round = (n, p = 0) =>
  Math.round(n * 10 ** p) / 10 ** p
```

We can get **all** solutions -

```js
const solutions =
  Array.from(subsetSums([3.27,9,8,6.8,4,5.5,7,10.07], 15.57))
```

Or maybe we just want the `first` solution. Because generators are cancellable, this means that no work will be done after returning the first value -

```js
function first (it)
{ for (const v of it)
    return v
}

const solution =
  first(subsetSums([3.27,9,8,6.8,4,5.5,7,10.07], 15.57))
```

We could wrap this into a simple HTML `form` using some additional generic functions, `stepper`, which steps through any generator, and `json`, which creates a text node with `JSON.stingify`'d contents -

```js
function* stepper (it, f)
{ let x = it.next()
  while (!x.done) (yield f(x.value), x = it.next())
  while (true) yield f("no more results")
}

function json(value)
{ const e = document.createElement("pre")
  e.textContent = JSON.stringify(value)
  return e
}
```

Now all we have to do is connect this to our form -

```html
<form id="solver">
  <button type="button" name="next">next</button>
  <output name="output"></output>
</form>
```

```js
const f =
  document.forms.solver
  
const solver =
  stepper
    ( subsetSums([3.27,9,8,6.8,4,5.5,7,10.07], 15.57)
    , solution => 
        f.output.appendChild(json(solution))
    )
    
f.next.addEventListener("click", _ => solver.next())
```

Run the snippet below to see the results in your own browser -

```js
function* subsetSums(numbers, target, precision = 2)
{ function* solve(i, q, r)
  { if (q == 0) return yield r
    if (numbers.length < i || q < 0) return
    // solve with this number
    yield *solve
      ( i + 1
      , round(q - numbers[i], precision)
      , [...r, {pos: i, n: numbers[i]}]
      )
    // solve without this number
    yield *solve(i + 1, q, r)
  }
  yield *solve(0, target, [])
}

function* stepper (it, f)
{ let x = it.next()
  while (!x.done) (yield f(x.value), x = it.next())
  while (true) yield f("no more results")
}

function json(value)
{ const e = document.createElement("pre")
  e.textContent = JSON.stringify(value)
  return e
}

const round = (n, p = 0) =>
  Math.round(n * 10 ** p) / 10 ** p

const f =
  document.forms.solver
  
const solver =
  stepper
    ( subsetSums([3.27,9,8,6.8,4,5.5,7,10.07], 15.57)
    , solution => 
        f.output.appendChild(json(solution))
    )
    
f.next.addEventListener("click", _ => solver.next())
```

```html
<form id="solver">
  <button type="button" name="next">next</button>
  <output name="output"></output>
</form>
```

```js
[{"pos":0,"n":3.27},{"pos":3,"n":6.8},{"pos":5,"n":5.5}]
[{"pos":5,"n":5.5},{"pos":7,"n":10.07}]
"no more results"
```

The `numbers` input is not modified as a result of running `subsetSums`.